# why not a case with predicate guards in addition to pattern guards?

Tags: haskell, if-statement, switch-statement, predicate, pattern-guards

why not a case with predicate guards in addition to pattern guards?

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf, LambdaCase #-}

module Main where

import System.Info         (os)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Char           (toLower)
import Data.List           (isPrefixOf)

main :: IO ()
main = print . ($ toLower <$> os) $ \x -> if
  | "mingw" `isPrefixOf` x -> "windows"
  | "darwin" == x          -> "mac"
  | otherwise              -> "linux"
```

would be prettier as:

```
main = print $ case toLower <$> os of
  x | "mingw" `isPrefixOf` x -> "windows"
    | "darwin" == x          -> "mac"
    | otherwise              -> "linux"
```

or even:

```
main = print $ case toLower <$> os of
  | ("mingw" `isPrefixOf`) -> "windows"
  | ("darwin" ==)          -> "mac"
  | otherwise              -> "linux" -- when pattern absent: otherwise = const True
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you proposing new Haskell syntax?

Comment: It seems like a reasonable idea, but is it that useful?  I've never missed this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Your first proposal is valid syntax, so just use it:

```
main = print $ case toLower <$> os of
  x | "mingw" `isPrefixOf` x -> "windows"
    | "darwin" == x          -> "mac"
    | otherwise              -> "linux"
```

Comment: ha ha whoops, thanks for pointing that out.  :)  but i like the pointfree one, why not allow it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I thought you were aiming for a point-free case at all costs. Your pointful proposal is indeed correct syntax, as András Kovács points out.

Here is a pointless-style match:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
main = print $ case toLower <$> os of
  (("mingw" `isPrefixOf`) -> True) -> "windows"
  (("darwin" ==) -> True)          -> "mac"
  _                                -> "linux"
```

or even, without view patterns:

```
match :: a -> [(a -> Bool, b)] -> b
match x ((f,y):rest) | f x       = y
                     | otherwise = match x rest
match _ [] = error "Non exhaustive predicates"

main = print $ match (toLower <$> os)
     [(("mingw" `isPrefixOf`) , "windows")
     ,(("darwin"==)           , "mac")
     ,((const True)           , "linux")]
```

Comment: ah, thanks for the viewpatterns example.  i guess the question is 'would my 2nd proposal cause problems -- was it considered, and if so, why rejected'?

Comment: @user1441998 I don't know if it was considered, but since the first variant is just a few characters away, it makes it harder to add the second one as another special case in the Haskell grammar.